# Mutating column given a condition

Tags: r

I'm a beginner in R and I am stuck with the following..

```
df <- tibble(
  id = c(01, 02), 
  a = c(0.44, 0.42), 
  b = c(1, 0.42), 
  c = c(NaN, 0.71), 
  d = c(0.75, 0), 
  e = c(0.66, 0.75), 
  f = c(0.5, 0.22), 
  g = c(1, NaN), 
  h = c(0.8, NaN)
)
```

I wonder how I can mutate a column that counts the number of cases of cells >0 - separately for the columns a:d and e:h (&rowwise)

I have been thinking of something like this..

```
df1 <- df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(casesatod = length(which(., > 0), na.rm = TRUE),
         casesetoh = length(which(., > 0), na.rm = TRUE))
```

Of course, this code is not complete but to give you an idea of what I was thinking of..

I'd really looking forward to receiving help from you !

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2):

An option would be `rowSums` after selecting subset of columns from the dataset.  It would be more efficient than `rowwise` as it is vectorized

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    mutate(casesatod = rowSums(.[2:5] > 0, na.rm = TRUE), 
           casesetoh = rowSums(.[6:9] > 0, na.rm = TRUE))
```

---

If we need to use column names for selecting, use `select`

```
df %>%
   mutate(casesatod = rowSums(select(., a:d) > 0, na.rm = TRUE),
          casesetoh = rowSums(select(., e:h)  > 0, na.rm = TRUE))
# A tibble: 2 x 11
#     id     a     b      c     d     e     f     g     h casesatod casesetoh
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#1     1  0.44  1    NaN     0.75  0.66  0.5      1   0.8         3         4
#2     2  0.42  0.42   0.71  0     0.75  0.22   NaN NaN           3         2
```

Comment: @JoB seems like you have group_by attribute, try `df %>% ungroup %>%` and then uses `mutate` with correct index

Comment: Thanks a lot !
Unfortunately, I repeatedly get an error message when I try to apply your code to my original dataset which consists of 82 rows.. 
"Fehler: Column `casesS11toS14` must be length 2 (the group size) or one, not 156". 
Do you happen to have an explanation ?

Comment: @JoB  Is it the error even after `ungroup`  I don't think so

Comment: @JoB As I mentioend, I can reproduce the error whn there is a `group_by` and if it is `ungroup`ed, it will go away `iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% mutate(new = rowSums(.[1:3] > 0))
Error: Column `new` must be length 50 (the group size) or one, not 150`

Comment: WIth `ungroup`  `iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% ungroup %>% mutate(new = rowSums(.[1:3] > 0))
# A tibble: 150 x 6
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species   new
          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>   <dbl>
 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa      3`

Comment: yes, it works, I read your answer too late and reformulated my question, so everything's fine, thanks a lot again !